# How to fix my syntax error in phpmyAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm a complete beginner in working with sql and its only my first homework for database but already got an error and i cant seem to fix it. I appreciate any help offered.
[image]

I tried changing the data types, but there is still an error.
[image]

Comment: Posting images of technical information like code and errors, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: At a quick look, `varchar` without a given size is not allowed on that server.

Comment: When being a beginner, may I advise you to skip/delete/ignore PhpMyAdmin?  Try a better look like,  for example,  [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)

Comment: or, mysqlworkbench, see: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/